# Как вытащить изображения из кода?

Tags: python, json, парсер, bs4

Не получается скачать фото и получить ссылки.

Есть сайт

```
https://www.gzhel.ru/catalog/novyy/detail/suvenir-valenok-slozhnaya-rospis-tirazhnoe-1-sort-sht/
```

пытаюсь вытащить изображения в виде ссылок и сами изображения в папку.

Вот код:

```html
<a href="/upload/iblock/67b/e3gaxmjg12rstef270jyvlwiwzcxlhvt.png" data-fancybox="product-gallery" tabindex="-1">
  <img class="carousel-image flickity-lazyloaded" src="/upload/resize_cache/iblock/67b/644_644_140cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a/e3gaxmjg12rstef270jyvlwiwzcxlhvt.png" alt="" srcset="/upload/iblock/67b/e3gaxmjg12rstef270jyvlwiwzcxlhvt.png 2x">
</a>
```

ввожу запрос:

```py
soup.findAll('img', class_='carousel-image')
```

получаю:

```html
<img alt="" class="carousel-image" data-flickity-lazyload-src="/upload/resize_cache/iblock/a56/644_644_140cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a/37v3vw1t683b2jrgvq22tviy6f19zz88.jpg" data-flickity-lazyload-srcset="/upload/resize_cache/iblock/a56/1288_1288_140cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a/37v3vw1t683b2jrgvq22tviy6f19zz88.jpg 2x" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 490 490' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A"/>
```

а от сюда уже не могу вытащить..

Comment: В оконцовке у Вас должна получиться вот такая ссылка `https://www.gzhel.ru/upload/resize_cache/iblock/a56/644_644_140cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a/37v3vw1t683b2jrgvq22tviy6f19zz88.jpg`

Comment: Да. И если изображение не одно, то и ссылок соответственно...
Еще бы не плохо отдельно в папку их закачать..

Comment: @Илья, а в чём, собственно, проблема заключается? Осталось вытащить атрибут пути и по его значению загрузить изображение. В чём сложность?

Comment: Я в коде ковыряюсь 2 день....нашел видос, сделал все согласно примеру. остановился на том, что вытащить ссылку не могу (отделить), кучу всего перерыл и вот я здесь с тупым наверное вопросом...) Пробовал ['src'] не помогло...

Comment: Вроде бы элементы в BeautifulSoup имеют пропорцию `attrs`, там скорее всего и можно получить значение атрибута `data-flickity-lazyload-src`.

Comment: не получилось....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.gzhel.ru/catalog/novyy/detail/suvenir-valenok-slozhnaya-rospis-tirazhnoe-1-sort-sht/'

response = requests.get(url)
html = response.text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
img_tags = soup.find_all('img', class_='carousel-image flickity-lazyloaded')

img_links = [img['src'] for img in img_tags]

print(img_links)
```

Comment: Там вроде бы относительные ссылки. Лучше добавьте пример для получения абсолютных ссылок: `from urllib.parse import urljoin` + `urljoin(response.url, img['src'])`

Comment: Этот вариант не сработал.....

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.gzhel.ru/catalog/stolovaya-posuda/dlya-napitkov/shtofy/detail/shtof-kazak/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
img_tags = soup.find_all('img', class_="carousel-image")

# 644 x 644
print([f"https://www.gzhel.ru{x['data-flickity-lazyload-src']}" for x in img_tags])

# 1288 x 1288
print([f"https://www.gzhel.ru{x['data-flickity-lazyload-srcset'][:-3]}" for x in img_tags])
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Все получилось. Надо бы разобраться на будущее что к чему.